# How to use SHFileOperation() with CString paths

Tags: c++, string, winapi, mfc, null-terminated

I am trying to convert `CString` to `LPCWSTR` and it works well. But something went wrong in the processing of the code.

I want to copy a directory to another path so I am using `SHFILEOPSTRUCT`:

```
HWND console = GetConsoleWindow();
SHFILEOPSTRUCT s = { 0 };
s.hwnd = console;
s.wFunc = FO_COPY;
s.fFlags = FOF_SILENT;

CString _folderName("a6_töüst-Oa5Z.OZS-CI5O5235"),
        firstPath("C:\\ORTIM-Daten\\a5Pc 2.0.3\\Temp\\"),
        lastPart("\\Documents\\*\0"),
        firstPathDest("C:\\ORTIM-Daten\\a5Pc 2.0.3\\"),
        lastPartDest("Documents\\"),
        _folderNameDest("a6_töüst-Oa5Z.OZS-CI5O5235\0");

CString cstrTemp = firstPath + _folderName + lastPart,
    cstrTempDest = firstPathDest + lastPartDest + _folderNameDest;

s.pTo   = cstrTempDest /*_TEXT("C:\\ORTIM-Daten\\a5Pc 2.0.3\\Documents\\a6_töüst-Oa5Z.OZS-CI5O5235\0")*/;
s.pFrom = cstrTemp     /*_TEXT("C:\\ORTIM-Daten\\a5Pc 2.0.3\\Temp\\a6_töüst-Oa5Z.OZS-CI5O5235\\Documents\\*\0")*/;

SHFileOperation(&s);
```

When I am using `CString` directly, the copy operation doesn't work, but when I use the `_TEXT()` macro (as in the comments) to assign the `LPCWSTR` members in the struct everything works.

**EDIT 1**

In both variants of source and destination paths the code compiles.

In this variant, the code compiles and does the copy operation:

```
s.pTo   = _TEXT("C:\\ORTIM-Daten\\a5Pc 2.0.3\\Documents\\a6_töüst-Oa5Z.OZS-CI5O5235\0");
s.pFrom = _TEXT("C:\\ORTIM-Daten\\a5Pc 2.0.3\\Temp\\a6_töüst-Oa5Z.OZS-CI5O5235\\Documents\\*\0");
```

In the other variant, which I actually need, the code compiles too, but the copy operation doesn't take place:

```
 s.pTo   = cstrTempDest;
 s.pFrom = cstrTemp;
```

Comment: it works fine here, but you can try cstrTempDest.GetBuffer(0)

Comment: @ServeLaurijssen with your suggestion the copy operation don't work. Only the creation of the destination directory,-if it does not exist- works in this case. which means, that the struct can read the destination path "s.pTo" but cant do the copy operation for some reason!!

Comment: Is this project for UNICODE or ANSI? Is your CString the `wchar_t` variant? If you have a non-UNICODE project you need `MultiByteToWideChar` here.

Comment: @ServeLaurijssen `GetBuffer(0)` is the wrong approach because it doesn't garantuee that the string is zero-terminated. Use `Data()` instead.

Comment: Why are you using ANSI text in the first place? Start by fixing that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan how can i fix that?

Comment: Use `L"..."` rather than `"..."` and use `CStringW` rather than `CString` (or define `UNICODE` so that `CString` holds Unicode. You really don't want to be using `_TEXT()`. That's useful if you need to target Windows 98. You don't. Use Unicode text.

Comment: i looked in the setting of my project, am already using Unicode. and i have to use CString, because it is an old big project, which i have to modify.

Comment: `CString` is just a typedef. `CStringW` is the same thing, in case the `_UNICODE` preprocessor symbol is defined. Also, please provide a [mcve], throwing out all the unrelated parts.

Comment: Included code compiles without errors in Unicode and in Multi-Byte character set (checked with VC2013). Could you elaborate what isn't working.

Comment: @Orientos Instead of saying "this is an old project, I can't change anything", you need to shift your mindset. You need to spend time to understand Unicode. You won't make progress until you understand the options, until you know how your program handles Unicode. You seem to be resisting this, hoping that you can just magic a solution into place.

Answer (score 4):

`SHFILEOPSTRUCT` expects strings ending with **two** NUL characters, but NUL terminated strings by definition end with **one** and any additional NUL characters are ignored by `CString` methods that don't take explicit length argument.

You can force double NUL by adding one manually:

```
CString cstrTempDest = firstPathDest + lastPartDest + _folderNameDest;

// *** Add NUL manually ***
cstrTempDest.AppendChar( 0 );
s.pTo = cstrTempDest;

// For debuging - verify resulting string with example.
TCHAR* test = _TEXT("C:\\ORTIM-Daten\\a5Pc 2.0.3\\Documents\\a6_töüst-Oa5Z.OZS-CI5O5235\0");
// +2 because we want to check two NULs at end.
ASSERT( memcmp( s.pTo, test, (_tcslen(test)+2)*sizeof(TCHAR) ) == 0 );
```

Alternative solution can use methods with explicit length argument:

```
CString cstrTempDest = firstPathDest + lastPartDest
                           + CString(_folderNameDest, _tcslen(_folderNameDest)+1);
```

If your project is configured to use unicode character set, call `CString` constructors with wide strings:

```
CString _folderName(_T("a6_töüst-Oa5Z.OZS-CI5O5235")),
        firstPath(_T("C:\\ORTIM-Daten\\a5Pc 2.0.3\\Temp\\"))
        ...
```

`CString` in unicode mode automatically converts narrow strings to wide ones, but it can fail when threre is discrepancy between runtime and development codepages. If you plan to go Unicode and never look back, throw away `_TEXT`, `TEXT` and `_T` macros and just use wide literals:

```
CString _folderName( L"a6_töüst-Oa5Z.OZS-CI5O5235" ),
        firstPath( L"C:\\ORTIM-Daten\\a5Pc 2.0.3\\Temp\\" )
        ...
```

You should also check `SHFileOperation` return value.

Comment: thank you, that is the right solution and a constructive contribution

Comment: `CString` handles embedded nulls just fine, as your example shows. The real problem is when passing `"a6_töüst-Oa5Z.OZS-CI5O5235\0"` as-is to `_folderNameDest`, it is seen as a null-terminated string and ignores the terminator when initializing `_folderNameDest`. You can avoid by passing in a 2nd parameter for the string length to include the embedded terminator, eg: `LPCTSTR szFolderNameDest = TEXT("a6_töüst-Oa5Z.OZS-CI5O5235\0"); ... , _folderNameDest(szFolderNameDest, _tcslen(szFolderNameDest)+1);` Then you don't need to append the extra null terminator as a separate operation.

Comment: **@RemyLebeau** I have added your sugestion to answer.

Comment: This doesn't address the problems of using ANSI text

Comment: **@DavidHeffernan** Extended answer with the recommendation of consistent use of wide strings.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of user msp0815 on [creating double null ended CString](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0448c8e6-66e3-4b02-a208-99800f61957e/creating-double-null-ended-cstring) solves your issue.

```
// strings must be double-null terminated

CString from(cstrTemp + (TCHAR)'\0');
PCZZTSTR szzFrom= from;
s.pFrom= szzFrom;

CString dest(cstrTempDest + (TCHAR)'\0');
PCZZTSTR szzDest= dest;
s.pTo= szzDest;
```

Comment: Wow, I just learned that there is a [dedicated typedef](https://peterbudai.eu/blog/2012/07/18/windows-api-at-its-best/) for "double null-terminated" strings. For UNICODE it is declared as `typedef __nullnullterminated CONST WCHAR *PCZZWSTR;`. The `__nullnullterminated` is [SAL annotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog/header-annotations) so the compiler can do some checking.

Answer (score -3):

I generally don't use LPCWSTR that much but here is my idea:

```
CString TestCSTR = "Hello world";
LPCWSTR TestLPC;

TestLPC = (LPCWSTR)_TEXT(TestCSTR.GetString());
```

It works as expected in fact the variable TestLPC holds "Hello world" or to be more precise a long pointer to it. It should be possible to remove _TEXT without consequences but I'm not sure, the result is the same btw.

Comment: This will fail to compile, if `_UNICODE` is defined, an exhibit undefined behavior, if it isn't.

Comment: I'm curious, why it produces undefined behavior? Is it due to the fact that it cast into a pointer that may result in something not valid?

Comment: It's because you may be casting a `char*` to `wchar_t*`